# How to insert json path in mysql/mariadb when path doesn't exist or exists partially

Tags: json, mariadb

Trying to tell my MariaDB database to update a json (longtext) column. It works fine if the path exists. It works fine if the path doesn't exist and the path is one-dimensional. It breaks if the path is multi-dimensional and doesn't exist or partially exists.

`jsondata = {"firstname":"Bob","stats":{"height":"72","weight":"200"}}`

`UPDATE table SET jsondata = JSON_INSERT(jsondata, '$.lastname', 'Smith')` - Works

`UPDATE table SET jsondata = JSON_INSERT(jsondata, '$.stats.hair', 'Brown')` - Works

`UPDATE table SET jsondata = JSON_INSERT(jsondata, '$.stats.hair.color', 'Brown')` - Doesn't work

`UPDATE table SET jsondata = JSON_INSERT(jsondata, '$.car.make', 'Ford')` - Doesn't work

Is there a command I'm unaware of that would create paths where there are none?

I tried creating a recursive function that exploded the path on the period and inserted the path into the json document level-by-level, but it fell apart.

EDIT: I'll send $20 Zelle/Venmo to whoever helps me figure this out.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? These are different products, and in particular they have different implementations of JSON. You shouldn't assume that the solution for one will work for the other, so you should be clear about which one you are asking about.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB currently, but I'm early enough in the project that I could switch to MySQL if the solution to this issue is exclusive to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON_MERGE_PATCH()` function.

**<kbd>[DEMO fiddle (MySQL)](https://dbfiddle.uk/bAIXx9y1)</kbd>**

**<kbd>[DEMO fiddle (MariaDB)](https://dbfiddle.uk/XUEm_bX3)</kbd>**

Comment: AKINA! My good friend, thank you. How can I pay you for your help?

Comment: @Nick I doubt that this is reasonable. And even that this is possible.